# Solved ODE by two different methods; unable to prove the solutions are the same.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have a first order ODE:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2y}{x}=\frac{e^x}{x^2}\tag{1}$$

Noting that this is in the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)\tag{2}$$ So an integrating factor method can be used.

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have that $P(x)=\dfrac{2}{x}$ and $Q(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^2}$.

So I find the the Integrating factor $I$ to be $$I=e^{\int\frac{2}{x}dx}=x^2$$ Now applying the standard formula:

> $$y=e^{-I}\int Q(x)e^I\,dx+Ce^{-I}\tag{3}$$

I find that $$\fbox{$y=e^{-x^2}\int\frac{e^x}{x^2}e^{x^2}\,dx+Ce^{-x^2}$}\tag{4}$$

The book answer is as follows:

> Multiplication of $(1)$ by the Integrating factor $x^2$ results in $$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=e^x$$ The LHS can be written as the derivative of a product: $$\left(yx^2\right)^{\prime}=e^x$$ So integrating both sides gives $$yx^2=e^x+C$$ or $$\fbox{$y=\frac{e^x+C}{x^2}$}\tag{5}$$

Equations $(4)$ and $(5)$ **must** be equivalent, but I am struggling to show that $(4)$ and $(5)$ are the same equation.

Is there anyone that can prove that $(4)$ and $(5)$ are the same?

---

### EDIT:

An answer to this question indicates that my quoted formula $(3)$ is wrong so I have provided an image of the book extract containing $(3)$:

[image: Book extract]

So is the book really wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equation $(3)$ is wrong, it must be
$$y=\frac{1}{\mu(x)}\left[\int \mu(x)Q(x)dx+C\right]\tag{3}$$
where $$\mu(x)=e^{\int\frac2{x}dx}$$

---

The book is not wrong, notice that
$$\frac{dI}{dx}=P\qquad\implies\qquad I=\int Pdx$$
According to the book we have
$$I=\int Pdx=\int\frac2xdx=2\ln|x|+c$$
while you are taking $I=e^{\int Pdx}$

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of completion to show that both the formula and the book method give the same answer:

> The formula: $$y=e^{-I}\int Q(x)e^I\,dx+Ce^{-I}\tag{3}$$ gives the correct solution provided that $\displaystyle I=\int P(x)\,dx$.

Then $\displaystyle I=\int P(x)\,dx=\int\frac2xdx=2\ln|x|$

By insertion of $I$ and $Q(x)$ into $(3)$:
$$y=e^{-2\ln|x|}\int \frac{e^x}{x^2}e^{2\ln|x|}\,dx+Ce^{-2\ln|x|}$$
$$=\frac{1}{x^2}\int \frac{e^x}{x^2}x^2\,dx+\frac{C}{x^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{x^2}\int \frac{e^x}{x^2}x^2\,dx+\frac{C}{x^2}$$
$$=\fbox{$y=\frac{e^x+C}{x^2}$}$$ which is the same as $(5)$.